Mounting Sconces to old junction box in wall
I know this has been covered a bit a few years ago, but that thread didn't give me much.
I am replacing some old sconces in my 1920s house, plaster and lath walls. There is lead paint in there somewhere, I have tested. Wires are cloth wrapped, but in fine condition. The sconces that were on there originally were just screwed into lath with wood screws.box one

The boxes don't seem to have any mounting points for the sconces. Aside from replacing the boxes with modern ones, what are some good enough options? Like I said, I don't want to replace with modern boxes because I don't want to deal with lead paint from cutting into the wall, and fussing with the wiring more than needed.
Attached are some photos.
Could it be that the two screws on the edges of the box are for sconces?

Yes the screws at the edges are mounting points.  (yellow lines)

You may need to purchase a set of ceiling mounts  ( work for wall as well as ceiling)  Then if the screws in the box are not aligned for the mounting holes in your sconces, you have the ability to adjust where the screws line up.

Oh, right on. That makes sense. I'm always reluctant to start messing with stuff without knowing for sure. Thanks

Hopefully the spacing on the screws matches the new sconce!

If they don't, that is one of the issues the ceiling mount corrects.
